# How to create a summary of my code

Tags: java

I want to automatically create some sort of report of my code(java).
Example:
I have something like:

```
public classe qwerty{
//CODE
/*
* Converts ...
* @param s
*        -string...
*/
public static int mult(string s)
   {
   //CODE
   } 
}
```

And I want to create something that looks like this:

```
...............................
public static int mult(string s)
Converts ...

Paramters:
   s (String): string...
Returns (int)
.................................
ETC
```

Is there any tool for that??

Comment: Have you looked at javadoc? If not, it is probably the tool you are looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225447/doxygen-vs-javadoc

Comment: I believe that the Eclipse IDE assists you in creating JavaDocs, a documentation format for Java code. You just need to type `/**` to start the documentation comment block AFTER you write the method.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are searching for [javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)

Javadoc creates html-files of your code as a documentation. Just look at some [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: After reading this it is inded what I want but can it make a Word document?

Comment: No; why would you want that?

Comment: There used to be MIF Doclet for PDF purposes

Comment: @LouisWasserman
Because I already have the report in Word I just need to add the functions and constructor etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have looked at javadoc, and it is not suitable for you, then look at this solution

[How to read Javadoc comments by reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504013/how-to-read-javadoc-comments-by-reflection)

look at answer "doclet"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **IntelliJ** then before the method you want to comment you have to type **/**** and hit enter. It automatically creates a comment with params or without depending on your function.